# How to store multiple form submissions as separate values in localStorage?

Tags: angular

With this code, I am only able to store a single key/value pair in localStorage, and if the user enters a new value and submits the form it overrides the previous one. How can I store each form submission in localStorage?

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({    
  selector: 'app-registration',  
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
 
  myform!:any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myform = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl('')
    });
}

  onSubmit() {
    localStorage.setItem("formdata",JSON.stringify(this.myform.value));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to add an item in the array that you are using in the localstorage. Try getting first the data from the localstorage, add the item and sending it again. It will look like this:

```
onSubmit(){
      
      let arrayName = localStorage.getItem("formadata")
      arrayName.push(this.myform.value)
      localStorage.setItem("formdata",JSON.stringify(arrayName));
    
  }
```

Comment: hoe can i done it using array and not to store duplicate entry

Comment: You can just store the array in the localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your previous `localStorage` entry with each `onSubmit()`, as you are giving the entry in `localStorage` the same "key" value.

A way to overcome this would be to give each `localStorage` entry that is saved in `onSubmit()` a unique identifer of some kind in it's "key" value.

One possible solution is to get the exact "time" in hours, minutes, seconds value (will be unique) and put that info in the "key" parameter of `setItem()`.

This will generate a single, unique `localStorage` entry for every `onSubmit()` that is called.

Try something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({    
  selector: 'app-registration',  
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
 
  myform!:any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myform = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // Generate Unique Identifier using Hours, Minutes, Seconds of submittal
    const today = new Date();
    const uniqueTimeEntry = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    localStorage.setItem("formdata-" + uniqueTimeEntry, JSON.stringify(this.myform.value));
  }

}
```

If you are instead NOT trying to create individual `localStorage` entries for each form submittal, you could simply add the subsequent form submittals to the existing `localStorage`, without overwriting it:

```
onSubmit() {
  // Get localStorage by key, then append the new data.
  let prevEntries = localStorage.getItem("formdata");
  prevEntries.push(this.myform.value);
  localStorage.setItem("formdata", JSON.stringify(prevEntries));
}
```